# Image upload not working with event.preventDefault() CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have created a form in CodeIgniter for uploading an image.

The View file:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url().'promotions/add_item' ?>" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="form-horizontal" id="addItem">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Image</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="file" name="pro_image">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

The Ajax code:

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#addItem" ).submit(function( event ) {
           var url = $(this).attr('action');
                $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: $("#addItem").serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('method')
              }).done(function(data) {
                  $('#ret').html(data);
                  // window.location.reload();
                $('#addItem')[0].reset();
              });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Controller file:

```
<?php
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title','Title','required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');

var_dump($_FILES['pro_image']);
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-danger"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button><small>'.  validation_errors().'</small></div>';
} else {

    if ($_FILES['pro_image']['size'] > 0) {
        $this->upload->initialize(array( 
        "upload_path" => './uploads/',
        "overwrite" => FALSE,
        "encrypt_name" => TRUE,
        "remove_spaces" => TRUE,
        "allowed_types" => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
        ));

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pro_image')) {
            echo 'Error :'. $this->upload->display_errors();
        }

        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $img = $data['file_name'];
    } 

    $title = $this->input->post('title');
    $description = $this->input->post('description');

    $this->promotions_model->add_item($title, $description,'uploads/'.$img);
}
```

Whenever I attempt to upload an image it always comes as `null`, but if I comment out the `event.preventDefault();` line then upload an image, then it works fine. However, then the other functionality like validation and return messages fail to work properly.

Can any one please tell me what is issue with `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: write `event.preventDefault()`   above `var url = $(this).attr('action');`

Comment: remove action in form and add that in ajax URL

Comment: i have try both but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $( "#addItem" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
       var url = $(this).attr('action');
       var data= new FormData($("#addItem")[0]);
            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            contentType:false,
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            data: data,
            type: 'POST' // POST/GET
            success:function(data) {
              $('#ret').html(data);
              $('#addItem')[0].reset();
             } 
          });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  event.preventDefault(); in the begining sumbit listner

Comment: i have try that but still same issue

Comment: " event.preventDefault();" will prevent the event to do any further action  related the event.  Hope, you don't need the " event.preventDefault();" in your script, as you are posting the form through ajax.

Comment: if i comment that line then when ever form is submit and return any message then its not showing properly my design crash

Comment: i dont understand is why my image is not upload when i submit form with  event.preventDefault() if i comment this line and then upload image then its working fine